# How to marshall XML with dynamic element using JAXB2

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm developing an SOAP client and I'm looking for more sophisticated solution to marshalling objects into XML-string using Jaxb2 library.

The goal is to marshall an object, which acts as a wrapper for any-type element. Example:

```
<Action id="5">
   <Employee id="10">
      <Name>John</Name>
   </Employee>
</Action>
```

or.

```
 <Action id="5">
    <Department id="ABC">
       <Name>Economy Department</Name>
       <ParentId>CDE</ParentId>
    </Department>
 </Action>
```

Note: The xml root (Action) contains either "Employee" or "Department" or anything else.

My current working solution is as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Action")
abstract class Action {

   @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
   protected String id;

}

class EmployeeAction extends Action {
    
   @XmlElement(name = "Employee")
   protected Employee employee;

}

class DepartmentAction extends Action {
    
   @XmlElement(name = "Department")
   protected Department department;

}
```

This works fine, but I'm looking for more universal solution, without the need to create class for each type (*Action extends Action). Name of the element must always be the same as the className of the (dynamic) type. My idea is something like this:

```
public class Action<T> {

   @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
   protected String id;

   @XmlElement(name = "getClass().getSimpleName()") //???
   protected T element;

}
```

... and marshalling something like:

```
Action<?> action = ...;

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Action.class, action.getElement().getClass());
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

try(ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
   marshaller.marshal(action, outStream);
   return outStream.toString();
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this for the above-provided XML:

**METHOD-1**

Action.class;

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Action")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Action {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    protected String id;

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "Employee", type = Employee.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "Department", type = Department .class),
    })
    private ActionItem type;
}
```

ActionItem.class;

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ActionItem {
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    protected String name;
}
```

Employee.class;

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Employee extends ActionItem {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;
}
```

Department.class;

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Department extends ActionItem {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "ParentId")
    private String parentID;
}
```

Main.class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Unmarshalling.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("action.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Action.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final Action action = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Action.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(action.toString());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Action.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(action, System.out);
    }
}
```

If you provided `Employee` XML then it produces the following result:

```
Action(id=5, type=Employee(id=10))
<Action id="5">
   <Employee id="10">
      <Name>John</Name>
   </Employee>
</Action>
```

If you provide the `Department` XML then it produces the following result:

```
Action(id=5, type=Department(parentID=CDE))
<Action id="5">
   <Department>
      <Name>Economy Department</Name>
      <ParentId>CDE</ParentId>
   </Department>
</Action>
```

**METHOD-2**

Creating the interface and using it:

```
public interface ActionItem2 {
}
```

Action.class uses the created interface.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Action")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Action {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    protected String id;

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "Employee", type = Employee.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "Department", type = Department .class),
    })
    private ActionItem2 type;
}
```

Employee.class which implements the created interface

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Employee implements ActionItem2 {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    protected String name;
}
```

Department.class which implements the created interface

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Department implements ActionItem2 {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "ParentId")
    private String parentID;

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    protected String name;
}
```

Main.class(No changes)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        final InputStream inputStream = Unmarshalling.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("action.xml");
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Action.class).createUnmarshaller();
        final Action action = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Action.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(action.toString());

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Action.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(action, System.out);
    }
}
```

The result would be the same.

**Method - 3**

If you don't want to modify your POJO then you can do something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Action")
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Action {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    protected String id;

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "Employee", type = Employee.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "Department", type = Department .class),
    })
    private Object type;
}
```

Employee.class:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Employee {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    protected String name;
}
```

Department.class:

```
@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Department {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlElement(name = "ParentId")
    private String parentID;

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    protected String name;
}
```

This will provide the same output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Acceptable solution, but is there any other solution which does not require my Employee and Department class to be modified (with extends)? My entity classes are generated from XSD schema each build. Thanks!

Comment: @CSB Modified the answer with `Method-3`. Check it out. Do upvote if it was helpful.